# How to load interstitial ad just after app launching

Tags: ios, swift, interstitial

Here is my code.It is not working. Build & run succeeded but no interstitial ad loading. What can i do?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")

        let request = GADRequest()
        // Requests test ads on test devices.
        request.testDevices = ["2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"]
        self.interstitial.loadRequest(request)
        load()

    }
    func load() {
        if self.interstitial.isReady {
            self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it in ViewDidAppear event, i remember i had this issue before

Comment: override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
        
        let request = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = ["2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"]
        self.interstitial.loadRequest(request)
        load()
        if self.interstitial.isReady {
            self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
        }

    }   //still not working

Comment: Not the cleanest way but you might need to use NSTimer to make a delay on when to load it :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if self.interstitial.isReady {
        self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to explain that whats going on in the code